# How to use tough-cookie in nodeJS HTTPS request

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to create a https request to a remote system which requires digest authentication as well as 
support for cookies. I am using tough-cookies to get all cookies from the remote server via

```
 if (res.headers['set-cookie'] instanceof Array)
  cookies = res.headers['set-cookie'].map(Cookie.parse);
  else
  cookies = [Cookie.parse(res.headers['set-cookie'])];
```

which works fine and my cookies look like this

```
[
  Cookie="JSESSIONID=7A7A3A034A17B8DF7737BAF017ED4698; Path=/contact; HttpOnly; hostOnly=?; aAge=?; cAge=0ms",
  Cookie="JSESSIONID=7A7A3A034A17B8DF7737BAF017ED4698; Path=/contact; hostOnly=?; aAge=?; cAge=0ms"
]
```

How can i now on the next request just send the key and values ?

Comment: i am using https.requests to make the requests

Comment: That does not address my issue at all. I know how to manually add a cookie but I want to use the cookies stored in tough cookie